# Junit test fails on call to InitialContext() using Simple-jndi (simple-jndi-0.18.2.jar)

Tags: java, junit, jndi

I'm trying to test a web app which connects to the database - my Junit code does not do the connection.

Setup is per https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI

Failure is on InitialContext()

Many of these errors are thrown:

SEVERE: path: [path][class].java ctxt: javax.naming.InitialContext@5e29e202 subName: 
Sep 16, 2019 10:24:39 AM org.osjava.sj.loader.NioBasedJndiLoader$MySimpleFileVisitor visitFile
SEVERE: 
javax.naming.NotContextException: rConfig already occupied by new RequestConfig(config, logger);

These are not JNDI names.

jndi.properties is correctly placed and is located at runtime.
datasource.properties is also set up.

Code being tested (ie, can't be changed) is

```
cntxt = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) cntxt.lookup(databaseResource);
conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two properties, xml or ini files found in the org.osjava.sj.root directory with an "rConfig" entry and that these files are in the same subdirectory. The first file found applied "new RequestConfig(config, logger)" to "rConfig", e. g.

```
rConfig = new RequestConfig(config, logger)
```

Perhaps org.osjava.sj.root does not point to the place you expect it to point to.